# Android Toolbar: Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I use the new Toolbar in my Android App. I want the same behauviour theme like "Light.DarkActionBar". So that my content background are white. The textes etc. are black. And my ActionBar/Toolbar have a custom background and also white Textes and Overflow-Menus.
So I implement these in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

The Toolbar implementation loks like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        app:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

But it looks not like a want. The Toolbar-Text and the Toolbar back-Button (`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`) looks still black!!! 
Want I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you set AppCompatTheme as theme? I don't see you using it in your layouts. And even if you'd set it as app theme you're overloading it with ThemeOverlay.AppCompat styles in your layouts. Try using AppCompatTheme in your manifest and only overload app:popupTheme in your layout to get the popups white.

Comment: I set in my AndroidManifest like that:  android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme". When I only use app:popupTheme it changes absolutlie nothing....

Comment: I checked my own project: I am using this as styles and it works fine: app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" and app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark". I also have android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" set on the Toolbar Widget. Maybe you have to replace android:background="@color/primaryColor" with android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" to get it working.

Comment: I have the same problem, my toolbar configuration is exactly like the one above, and my app:xlmns is correct. But the title and the home icon is still black. Any solution?

Comment: Above works for Lollipop, on Kitkat back icon and textColor will be still black. @Jürgen'Kashban'Wahlmann that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the bug. The

```
xmls:app
```

namenspace had the wrong URI. It was

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

for whatever reason...
I changed it to the right one:

```
xmls:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Now it works like I want.